# Building a seatmap with kind of wings for the plane

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have to build a seatmap for planes, using only HTML, CSS and jQuery. In general that's no problem, but I don't know how to add wings to the plane.
Currently I mark the seats (which are placed over the wings) with a darker outside border. But this is not nice. I would like to add kind of "wings" to the plane itself where they have to be. Or, if not wings-style, at least there should be a border on the "plane outside". Any ideas how to do this?

```
<div id="seatmap">
    <div id="plane">
        <table class="rows">
        <tr>
            <td>F</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>D</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <div id="cabin">        
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td title="1F" class="seatAvailable"></td>
                <td title="2F" class="seatUnavailable"></td>
                <td title="" class="noSeatGalley"></td>
                <td title="4F" class="ExtraPay"></td>
                <td title="5F" class="seatAvailable wingSeat"></td>
                <td title="6F" class="seatUnavailable wingSeat"></td>
                <td title="7F" class="seatAvailable wingSeat"></td>
                <td title="8F" class="noSeatStorage wingSeat"></td>
                <td title="9F" class="seatAvailable"></td>
                <td title="10F" class="seatAvailable"></td>
                <td title="11F" class="seatAvailable LargeSeat"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td title="1D" class="seatAvailable"></td>
                <td title="2D" class="seatUnavailable"></td>
                <td title="" class="noSeatGalley"></td>
                <td title="4D" class="ExtraPay"></td>
                <td title="5D" class="seatAvailable"></td>
                <td title="6D" class="seatUnavailable"></td>
                <td title="7D" class="seatAvailable"></td>
                <td title="8D" class="noSeatStorage"></td>
                <td title="9D" class="seatAvailable"></td>
                <td title="10D" class="seatAvailable"></td>
                <td title="11D" class="seatAvailable ExtraPay LargeSeat"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="noSeatGalley">1</td>
                <td class="noSeatGalley">2</td>
                <td class="noSeatGalley"></td>
                <td class="noSeatGalley">4</td>
                <td class="noSeatGalley">5</td>
                <td class="noSeatGalley">6</td>
                <td class="noSeatGalley">7</td>
                <td class="noSeatGalley">8</td>
                <td class="noSeatGalley">9</td>
                <td class="noSeatGalley">10</td>
                <td class="noSeatGalley">11</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td title="1C" class="seatAvailable"></td>
                <td title="2C" class="seatAvailable"></td>
                <td title="" class="noSeatGalley"></td>
                <td title="4C" class="ExtraPay"></td>
                <td title="5C" class="seatUnavailable"></td>
                <td title="6C" class="seatAvailable"></td>
                <td title="7C" class="seatAvailable"></td>
                <td title="8C" class="noSeatLavatory"></td>
                <td title="9C" class="seatAvailable"></td>
                <td title="10C" class="seatAvailable"></td>
                <td title="11C" class="seatAvailable ExtraPay LargeSeat"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td title="1A" class="seatAvailable"></td>
                <td title="2A" class="seatAvailable"></td>
                <td title="" class="noSeatGalley"></td>
                <td title="4A" class="ExtraPay"></td>
                <td title="5A" class="seatUnavailable wingSeat"></td>
                <td title="6A" class="seatAvailable wingSeat"></td>
                <td title="7A" class="seatAvailable wingSeat"></td>
                <td title="8A" class="noSeatLavatory wingSeat"></td>
                <td title="9A" class="seatAvailable"></td>
                <td title="10A" class="seatAvailable"></td>
                <td title="11A" class="seatUnavailable ExtraPay LargeSeat"></td>
            </tr>
            </table>            
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle 1: http://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/0Lu4vspq/1/

OK, I have another Fiddle, a bit updated.
Here we have a better idea of where the wings are (or should be) ->
Fiddle 2: http://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/0Lu4vspq/3/

The problem still is, that I want the border on the outside of the plane, not inside the cabin.

Comment: Very well done. For drawing diagonal lines for your wings, I found this: http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/B95wX/3/  Hope it helps.

Comment: Thx for that. I think I just don't know exactly how to use this? When I place my seatmap content to the space called "place your content here" I only can see three added horizontal lines below the so called "plane"

Comment: That UI looks the part! :)

Comment: I don't know what that means?

Comment: It looks very good :)

Comment: oh, thanks a lot :-) It would just look even better with real wings...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my solution, with a CSS for the two wings:

http://jsfiddle.net/0Lu4vspq/6/

```
#wings {
    border: solid 5px #333;
    width: 80px;
    position: relative;
    left: 155px;
}
```

And

```
<div id="wings"></div>
```

Before and after your code.

**UPDATE**

You can edit dynamically the CSS via PHP. You need a different value but in a plane there are only two wings.

If there position are the same (or not, you can use two CSS codes for wing left and wing right) you have only to find the point where the wing start and its length.

At this point the CSS change in this two points:

```
#wings {
    border: solid 5px #333;
    width: 80px;   % <-- Length the wing
    position: relative;
    left: 153px;   % <-- Where the wing start
}
```

**SECOND UPDATE**

If you would like something more like a wing, the CSS will be:

```
#wings_down {
    left: 155px;
    width: 80px;
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
       -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
         -o-transform: skew(20deg);
    transform: skew(20deg);
    background: #333;
}

#wings_up {
    left: 155px;
    width: 80px;
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
       -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
         -o-transform: skew(-20deg);
    transform: skew(-20deg);
    background: #333;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0Lu4vspq/17/

Note: I have removed `border: solid 5px #333;` because it is redundant.

Comment: My wings are two rectangle. With more work they can be done more similar to the two wings.

Comment: Did you forget to update your fiddle? That link is the same one which was posted by the OP. Also, If you are planning to add `<div id="wings"></div>` more than once, you should give it a class and not use an ID - an ID can only be used once per page.

Comment: The idea itself is not that bad. I just have to think about how I can position the wings dynamicly. I get the position of the wings from a datebase and currently write it down into a tablerow. So I know that seat 5 or 34 or eg.. is above the wings.

Comment: @GiacomoAlessandroni: Aside from the positioning problem, it would stilll be interesting how these rectangles could look more like a wing?

Comment: @GiacomoAlessandroni: these wings look awesome! Unfortunatly it is not cross browser compatible. e.g. does not work in IE11 :-/ And regarding the positioning: I cannot use PHP in this project.
EDIT: OK, I see.. you just forgot the standard definition in there. I have added transform: skew(20deg); and it looks nice everywhere. 
New version here: http://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/0Lu4vspq/15/

Comment: Well, I insert your improve in my answer for all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71701/discussion-between-giacomo-alessandroni-and-schweizerschoggi).

Comment: I accept your solution as the best given answer, because you have re-developed your first idea based on my further questions and problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had a play adding a class of `wingRowTop` and `wingRowBottom` to the `tr` which has the `wingseat`.

http://jsfiddle.net/0Lu4vspq/4/

or with `:before` in the first cells to create a slope on the wings (in red so you can see)
http://jsfiddle.net/0Lu4vspq/5/

using negative margins and border-collapse, this is what I came up with.
I'm sure with some more HTML classes and border-radius that its possible to create a wing shape in the cells.

```
.wingRowTop {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0px;
position:absolute;
margin-top:-37px;

}
.wingRowBottom {
position:absolute;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0px;
}
#cabin tr:first-child td.wingSeat { background-color: #DEDEDE; border-right:5px solid #DEDEDE;}
#cabin tr:last-child td.wingSeat { background-color: #DEDEDE; border-right:5px solid #DEDEDE
```

Comment: This Idea is not that bad...! I have updated your version once again and yeah, maybe we can make something out of this: http://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/0Lu4vspq/7/

Answer (score 2):

So, I saw this and funnily enough, I'm writing a simulator for airport checkin. So thankyou @SchweizerSchoggi for asking the question and keeping the idea going.

One thing I thought would be useful is a generator for the seatmap, I've made a first attempt over at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mikebert4/0Lu4vspq/34/

On my todo will be to make this into a proper constructor object, ie:

```
var seatmap = new SeatMap(options);
```

Also, this only renders full rows of seats (uses Math.floor() to calculate the number of rows to display. But it's a start!

Comment: thanks for sharing! I can lern a lot from this regarding the JS part! Pretty straightforward!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your great support! At the end I am going to use a combination of both of your solutions: 
Wf4 has included the given solution regarding wings positioning and worked out the first "wings outside the cabin" approach. Giacomo Alessandroni meanwhile had a great idea for the wings layout.

Here is my final Fiddle: 
http://tinyurl.com/kr5de25