# Seatmap with kind of wings - reopened

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Yesterday I've asked for a solution to draw kind of wings to a plane (used for a seatmap). This question (and it's "solution") can be found here:
[Building a seatmap with kind of wings for the plane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722962/building-a-seatmap-with-kind-of-wings-for-the-plane)

We got a solution, but now I see the next problem: as long as the content is small enough that the cabin must not scroll, it's fine. But as soon as I have so many seat rows that the content beginns to scroll, the wings have to move with the seats. They should not stay in their old place, as it is important for the customer to know if his seat will be over a wing of the plane or not.

See Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/0Lu4vspq/26/

```
<div id="seatmap">
    <div id="plane">

        <table class="rows">
            <tr><th>E</th></tr>
            <tr><th>D</th></tr>
            <tr><th></th></tr>
            <tr><th>C</th></tr>
            <tr><th>A</th></tr>
        </table>


        <div id="cabin">        
            <table>
            <tr class="wingRowTop">
                <td class="noSeatGalley"></td>
                <td class="noSeatGalley"></td>
                <td class="noSeatGalley"></td>
                <td class="noSeatGalley"></td>
                <td class="wingSeat"></td>
                <td class="wingSeat"></td>
                <td class="wingSeat"></td>
                <td class="wingSeat"></td>
                <td class="wingSeat"></td>
                <td class="noSeatGalley"></td>
                <td class="noSeatGalley"></td>
                <td class="noSeatGalley"></td>
                <td class="noSeatGalley"></td>
                <td class="noSeatGalley"></td>
                <td class="noSeatGalley"></td>
                <td class="noSeatGalley"></td>
                <td class="noSeatGalley"></td>
                <td class="noSeatGalley"></td>
                <td class="noSeatGalley"></td>
                <td class="noSeatGalley"></td>
                <td class="noSeatGalley"></td>
            </tr>
[...]
```

Thx for any idea how to make the wings more flexible (scrollable)!!
Be aware that the dimensions of the plane are not fix, a plane can have more or less rows.

Comment: I would suggest using pseudo elements for this.

Comment: can you explain this to me? What do you mean?

Comment: Pseudo effects can be placed on an element you so desire (and position according to parent) - [For example...](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/fzshLdmj/1/)

Comment: hmmm, my plane has to be build with tables and is landscape

Comment: pls look up pseudo elements - you can specify where they appear in relation to the 'real' element

Comment: something like: http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/0Lu4vspq/29/ - you might even want ti add a min-width: http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/0Lu4vspq/30/

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot create that shape with your current codes, because you have hidden overflow on the parent. You'll have to probebly completely re-design it.